# What does <C-@> do?

Tags: key-bindings, insert-mode

I have seen <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>@</kbd> being used in Insert Mode in [a VimGolf challenge](http://vimgolf.com/challenges/57343555fd77ad227900df4a). In this scenario it inserts the text that was last typed and switches to Normal Mode.

However, I wonder if this is the real purpose of this binding or just a side effect, so I tried to find information on what it does but found nothing on `:help` or Google.

So, the question is: Where can I find documentation about <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>@</kbd>?

Comment: (point 8 in romainl's answer)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [`:h i_CTRL-@`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-@):

> CTRL-@        Insert previously inserted text and stop insert.

Also the mappings existing in insert mode are referenced in [`:h insert.txt`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html)

Comment: Oops, I've been searching `:h C-@`. I feel a bit ashamed now. Thanks!

Comment: A lot of help topic begins with `CTRL` ;-)